# Why are new instances of a list being created when adding Tasks?

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await

I have an asp.net application in which the user can press a button to initiate a long-running operation, and may do so multiple times. Each time they do, I want to add the created task to a list so that later, when they want proceed to the next page, the page waits for all tasks in the list to be completed before redirecting.

I have the following structure:

```
private List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
private SemaphoreSlim mutex = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

// Simulate some work
private async Task MyWork()
{
    int t = 0;
    while (t < 5)
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        t ++;
    }
}

// Called in the button's eventhandler
public void DoWork()
{
    mutex.Wait();
    this.tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => MyWork());
    mutex.Release();
}
```

When debugging I find that each time DoWork accesses the list of tasks, the list is empty when the task gets added to it, seemingly creating a separate instance of the list each time. Also, when I access the list in another method later, the list is empty there.

Why is this happening instead of each task being added to the same list instance?

Comment: can you add the code where you instaniate class containing you DoWork method ?

Comment: So on user pressing a button a server side request is sent where you are adding the task to the list? Wont each server side request create a new context, and thus a new list? That might be the reason your list is of 0 length to begin with. Try with a static/singleton instance and see if it works

Comment: @sayahimad The constructor for the class doesn't interact with anything here.

Comment: @pmain8  do you instantiate your class many times ?

Comment: @sayahimad In theory it could be, but in my testing I'm only doing it once.

Comment: @peeyushsingh Creating a singleton works but I don't know that I'll be able to use that as a long-term solution if this class has multiple instances running for different types of processes at the same time.

Comment: As far as I'm concern, you are using a semaphore where your pattern would only require a lock. I would suggest to use lock or better: a SpinLock and follow the required pattern. Or use a concurrent collection. Like sysah ask, you better provide more code because with the little we have now, it would be hard to find what you do wrong.

Comment: @EricOuellet Fair point about the lock, but elsewhere I was awaiting a Task.WhenAll on the tasks list and wanted to lock there, but I can't lock an await operation. I understand that this is not much to go on but I'm integrating this into a much larger structure that would be difficult to concisely explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When ASP.NET gets a new request, it creates a new instance of your page. This is why you're always seeing an empty list.

What you **should** do is have your button handler create a request id (e.g., a Guid), insert that request into a reliable queue, and then update the session state with that request id. So instead of a list of tasks, you have a list of request ids (strings). Then have a separate worker process read from that queue and do the actual work. Finally, the "waiting" page should poll until the requests are all completed.